# Optimizing a sorting algorithm by replacing the one of the recursion with a another function

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

Currently I have this sorting algorithm:

```
public static void sort(int[] A, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) return;
    if(j == i+1) {
        if(A[i] > A[j]) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    } 
    else {
        int k = (int) Math.floor((j-i+1)/3);
        sort(A,i, j-k);
        sort(A,i+k, j);
        sort(A,i,j-k);
    }
}
```

It's sorting correctly, however, the asymptotic comparison is quite high: with T(n) = 3T(n-f(floor(n/3)) and f(n) = theta(n^(log(3/2)3)

Therefore, I'm currently thinking of replacing the third recursion `sort(A,i,j-k)` with an newly written, iterative method to optimize the algorithm. However, I'm not really sure how to approach the problem and would love to gather some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: i checked the code and it's working

Comment: So if I read this right, you sort the first 2/3 of the list, then the last 2/3, then the first 2/3 again. Not sure if this really always works, or how, but you certainly sort a total of 6/3 of the list. No wonder that's rather on the slow side.

Comment: @tobias_k yup, so I'm looking to optimize the algorithm by replacing the third recursion with a new method

Comment: Also, in step 2, the first half will already be sorted, and in the last step, both the first and second half are sorted, so you might just use a merge-algorithm here instead of a full sort. If you think this further, you could just sort the first and second half, without overlap, and then merge those, and thus reinvent [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)...

Comment: @tobias_k thank you so much for replying! Could you  provide an example so that I could visualize your thought process?

Comment: What are your constraints for "optimizing" the algorithm? Do you want the entire algorithm to consist of just one operation (sort) as opposed to sort-and-merge, or partition-and-sort? Otherwise, you would probably just optimize it to one of the established sort algorithms.

Comment: So my goal is to only modify the third recursion and replace it with a newly written method.

Comment: You might want to add to your question that this is a well-known "bad" sorting algorithm called [Stooge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort). It might add some context for the people that aren't sure if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correct, you first sort the first 2/3 of the list, then the last 2/3, then sort the first 2/3 again. This actually works, since any misplaced items (items in the first or last 2/3 that actually belong into the last or first 1/3) will be shifted and then correctly sorted in the next pass of the algorithm.

There are certainly two points that can be optimized:

- in the last step, the first 1/3 and the second 1/3 (and thus the first and second half of the region to sort) are already in sorted order, so instead of doing a full sort, you could just use a merge-algorithm, which should run in O(n)
- instead of sorting the first and last 2/3, and then merging the elements from the overlap into the first 1/3, as explained above, you could sort the first 1/2 and last 1/2 and then merge those parts, without overlap; the total length of array processed is the same (2/3 + 2/3 + 2/3 vs. 1/2 + 1/2 + 2/2), but the merging-part will be faster than the sorting-part

However, after the second "optimization" you will in fact have more or less re-invented [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: I see! However, since only the first and last 1/3 of the array are sorted but the second 1/3 isn't, how could I merge two sorted and one unsorted array into an array?  Do  I need to  implement some kind of sorting in the merging method?

Comment: @CSnewbie No, for merge both "halves" of the region to merge must be internally sorted. Note that in the second optimization, I suggested sorted the first and last 1/2, not 1/3.

Comment: What if I'm not allowed to modify the rest of the code but only the last recursion call? Would merge still work?

Comment: Yes, since you are merging the first 1/3 and second 1/3 which both are internally sorted.